# Accessing values from a map in a SOQL Query

Tags: apex, map

I am attempting to run a SOQL query where I need to check for the WhatId from a task in my map, to get the appropriate list of Opportunities to modify.

```
Map<Id, DateTime> tskMap = new Map<Id, DateTime>();
        Map<Id, DateTime> dtMap = new Map<Id, DateTime>();
        String checkID;
        Datetime prevDate;
        for(sObject s : scope){
            for(Task tsk : (Task)s)
            {
                checkID = tsk.WhatId;
                if(checkID == tsk.WhatId)
                    {
                        prevDate = tsk.CreatedDate;
                        if(prevDate >= tsk.CreatedDate)
                        {
                            tskMap.put(tsk.WhatId,tsk.CreatedDate);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        checkID = tsk.WhatId;
                        prevDate = tsk.CreatedDate;
                        tskMap.put(tsk.WhatId,tsk.CreatedDate); 
                    }
            }
        }
        for(List<Opportunity> oppyList : [Select Id, Last_Call_Log_Date__c from Opportunity where Id IN :tskMap.get(tsk.WhatId)])
            {
                for(Opportunity Oppy : oppyList)
                {

                }

            }
```

I am thinking that is has something to do with GET, but that seems to give me an error stating that the variable do not exist.

Can someone assist please? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
Select Id, Last_Call_Log_Date__c from Opportunity where Id IN :tskMap.KeySet()
```

Using `.KeySet()` on a map, you'll get a list of all the keys returned.

Comment: Thank you. That solved the issue of being able to do the SOQL Query, but what would it look like if I needed to use the date to do the compare?

Comment: you can use map.values() , map methods are well documented: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_map.htm